# ggplot change grid to fit monthly data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a 1-year dataset named *afs20*, which is structured as follows:

- *datum* contains the date of the data point
- *maand* contains the month of the data point
- *delta* contains the target variable

```
o = ggplot(afs20)      
o + 
  geom_point(aes(x = datum, y = delta),stat="identity") +
  theme_bw()
```

[My current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTIuB.png)

Now my question is: how do I align the vertical lines of the grid with the start of a new month? That is, I want a data point that occurs on the first day of the month to align with the grid of the plot, for every month.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly do you want? Aren't the grid lines already at the start of each month? If you want to play around with the grid, here is a blogpost, that explains some functionality: https://www.statworx.com/de/blog/customizing-time-and-date-scales-in-ggplot2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `date_minor_breaks` argument in the x-scale.
Example with build-in dataset below.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(head(economics, 50), aes(date, unemploy)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_minor_breaks = "1 month")
```

[image]